# There are several files providing this module error while running react native application

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have created an android module [from here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html) and added to my project. Now I am getting below error while running application.

bundling failed: ambiguous resolution: module `projectpath\index.js` tries to require `react-native`, but there are several files providing this module. You can delete or fix them:

Comment: You need to (a) explain what you are trying to achieve and (b) share code of what you have done so far. Thus far, it appears you are confusing Native Modules with Custom Components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution. following command help me to overcome above error

```
yarn start --reset-cache
```